# Do I need to stop / linger while a scan is in progress from a systems authority vessel?

Tags: elite-dangerous

When clearing a dock and leaving for another system/station, sometimes a systems authority vessel comes close and initiates a scan for illegal cargo and similar.

What if this scan comes in when I'm already charging the frame shift drive, should I abort to let the vessel complete its scan? Will I incur a fine if I jump in the middle of the scan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. Leaving before a scan completes is not a crime. You will not be fined for evading a scan, intentionally or otherwise.

Comment: I think there may be some sort of exception to this rule in relation to checkpoints in systems in a state of lockdown, but I'm not entirely sure. I'll look into that tonight. For the general case, though, you don't have to worry.

Comment: Now that I think about it, in the case of a checkpoint, you're interdicted by system authority, and you would probably be unable to evade scan in time due to FSD cooldown.

Comment: OK, thanks, just trying to piece together why I have sometimes gotten a fine or been attacked by the system vessels, guess I must have done something else wrong. I am still totally new to the game and I just learned that what is legal cargo in one system was illegal in another (trading tobacco from Eravate to LHS 3447), so perhaps that was it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Possibly, I'm not sure. You can check the legal status of cargo in the system map (click on a station controlled by the main faction of the system), and also in the cargo tab of the right panel. The only other real possibility would be docking violations.